# starting and stopping hsqldb from unit tests

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, hsqldb

I'm trying to create integration tests using hsqldb in an in memory mode. At the moment, I have to start the hsqldb server from the command line before running the unit tests. I would like to be able to control the hsqldb server from my integration tests. I can't seem to get this to all work out though from code.

Update:

This appears to work along with having a hibernate.cfg.xml file in the classpath:

```
org.hsqldb.Server.main(new String[]{});
```

and in my hibernate.cfg.xml file:

```xml
<property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:ww</property>
<property name="connection.username">sa</property>
<property name="connection.password"></property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
```

**Update** 
It appears that this is only a problem when running the unit tests from within Eclipse using jUnit and the built in test runner. If I run

```
 mvn test
```

they are executed correctly and there is no exception. Am I missing something as far as a dependency goes? I have generated the eclipse project using

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and my pom is:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>myproject</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.1.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test Dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
        <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-servlet-tester</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.24</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Provided -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.26</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.26</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ww_main</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

**Update** 
Ok, well not sure what exactly was going wrong here, but I seemed to have fixed it. I deleted all the files that HSQLDB created, as well as all of the created files in my Maven target folder, did a clean, recreated my eclipse .project using maven and refreshed the project in eclipse. I think I may have had something left over from a previous configuration that was throwing it off.

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use the following configuration (directly inspired by the [Hibernate tutorial](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-configuration)) without any problem:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:foobar"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>

    <mapping resource="..."/>

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When using an in-memory HSQLDB, there is no need to start anything explicitly. Just use the `mem:` protocol and the in-memory database will get started from JDBC.

#### See also

- [Unit-Testing Hibernate With HSQLDB](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1365222/Unit-Testing-Hibernate-With-HSQLDB)

Comment: This is exactly what I'm doing, but when I run the unit test I get a java.sql.SQLException: socket creation error. I also get a [main] WARN org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory - Could not obtain connection to query metadata from hibernate.

Comment: I've noticed that it also is always creating files in my classpath that I would expect to be created if I was using a file based DB and not an in memory one.

Comment: I'm giving you the answer for confirming that my configuration was correct, leading me to look at other reasons this was failing. Thanks!

Comment: @Casey Glad it's solved and thanks. I was actually about to answer: double check your config, you must have a conflict somewhere :)

Answer (score 2):

Try appending this to the jdbc url:

```
;ifexists=true;shutdown=true;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your shutdown method just do

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
st.execute("SHUTDOWN");
conn.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

What about starting server through `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("shell command here")`? You have to do it only once for all tests, so it won't add too big lag.

**Update**
Ok, looks like you've solved it yourself :)

**Update 2**
To execute some code once before (or after) unit tests, you can

```
static class TestWrapper extends TestSetup {
    TestWrapper(TestSuite suite) {
        super(suite);
    }

    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        // start db
    }

    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {
        // kill db
    }
}
```

Then, just wrap your test set in it: `new TestWrapper(suite)`

Comment: this hasn't quite solved it I don't think. I'm working on moving it into a test suite where it gets executed only once, but there seems to be something wrong with it. I can't quite put my finger on it yet though.

Comment: Updated. I did this stuff a lot, so just copypaste from my project :)

Answer (score 0):

check my hsqldb maven plugin :
https://github.com/avianey/hsqldb-maven-plugin

You can just start/stop it like jetty-maven-plugin or tomee-maven-plugin for your tests :

```xml
<plugin>

    <!-- current version -->
    <groupId>fr.avianey.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <!-- 
        default value for in memory jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
        override only values you want to change
    -->
    <configuration>
        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
        <path>mem:test</path>
        <address>localhost</address>
        <name>xdb</name>
        <username>sa</username>
        <password></password>
        <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS</validationQuery>
    </configuration>

    <!-- call start and stop -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-hsqldb</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-hsqldb</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help to start HSQL in server mode in a Unit test, but in the same JVM. 
Sample code runs org.hsqldb.server.WebServer (i.e. port 80) but you may use org.hsqldb.server.Server. You may call setPort on either to override default port.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784679/15789