# populating in memory hsqldb database from script

Tags: java, unit-testing, integration-testing, hsqldb

Is there a way that I can specify a script in the connection string pointing to my in memory hsqldb instance?

I was looking at this [article](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=java&seqNum=507) and it looks like it is possible, but I'm not sure how to formulate the string correctly or where to put the script file. Looking at the hsqldb documentation [here](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html) it doesn't appear to be the case.

What would my options here be for using this from java tests?

This is related to a previous hsqldb question here [starting and stopping hsqldb from unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018066/starting-and-stopping-hsqldb-from-unit-tests)

Comment: Do you use Hibernate and SchemaExport? If yes, then you can put an `import.sql` on the runtime classpath and Hibernate will load it.

Comment: I have not used SchemaExport. I exported some data out of another databased and created a script, but it doesn't appear that hibernate is seeing my script anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Use a file: database instead of mem:, but include "files_readonly=true" in the properties file. Changes to the database during tests will not be persisted.