# HSQLDB issue: Starting the HSQL database from Java Code

Tags: batch-file, hsqldb

when I have to run  HSQLDB for my application i have to do it from command prompt, so I always double-click the Server.bat (batch file) to start the server which contain:

```
java -classpath ..\war\WEB-INF\lib\hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.Server -database test
```

or type the start server command from command prompt.

But, my question is that can I start the HSQL database server by coding in my java code directly, no need to start it separately from the java application? what will be the code?

Note that I am using spring 2.5, spring seecurity 2.0.4 (annotation disable).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that https://javajazzle.wordpress.com/2011/06/23/embedded-database-in-java-use-of-hsqldb/

Comment: The link should be fixed or preferrably an answer posted here.

Comment: Fixed the link with another article with the same content.

Answer (score 0):

Sample code to start and stop the HSQL WebServer programmatically. Imports removed for brevity.

Keeping it simple, this code is not threadsafe. This is just sample code.

Also note that the in memory db will start automatically when it receives the first jdbc request. Also, shutdown the in memory db by executing the SQL command SHUTDOWN via jdbc.

Uses org.hsqldb.server.WebServer (i.e. the hsql db server uses http port 80), but you may use org.hsqldb.server.Server instead. You may call setPort on either to override the default port.

```
public class HsqlServer {

    /**
     * Start the hsql server locally, with an HTTP interface. Rightclick on this
     * class in Eclipse, and run.
     * 
     * @param args
     */

    private static WebServer ws;

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new HsqlServer().startDB();
    }

    public void stopDB() {
        if (ws != null) {
            try {
                ws.checkRunning(true);
                System.out.println("db is running. stopping now");
                stopServer2();
            }
            catch(HsqlException hsqle) {
                System.out.println("db is already stopped");
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("DB not started. it is null");
        }
    }

    private void stopServer2() {
        ws.shutdownWithCatalogs(Database.CLOSEMODE_NORMAL);
    }

    public void startDB() {
        // String[] argsToServer = { "--database.0",
        // "file:" + HsqlServerConst.dbFileName, "-dbname.0",
        // HsqlServerConst.dbName };
        // WebServer.main(argsToServer);

        if (ws != null) {
            try {
                ws.checkRunning(false);
                System.out.println("check running is false");
                startServer2();
            } catch (HsqlException hsqle) {
                // already running.
                System.out.println("Server is already running.");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            // start the server, it is null
            System.out.println("server is null, starting now");
            startServer2();
        }
    }

    private WebServer startServer2() {
        ws = new WebServer();
        ws.setDatabasePath(0, "file:" + HsqlServerConst.dbFileName);
        ws.setDatabaseName(0, HsqlServerConst.dbName);
        ws.start();
        return ws;
    }

}
```