# Starting hsqldb database programmatically

Tags: hsqldb

I want to programmatically start HSQLdb server.
I create a runnable like below and then start it in a thread.

```
   Runnable hsqlRunnable = new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {

                    HsqlProperties props = new HsqlProperties();
                    props.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:C:\Documents and Settings\BThirup\Application Data\Rockwell Automation\FactoryTalk ProductionCentre\logs\ApplicationLog\mydb;shutdown=true;");
                    props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "xdb");
org.hsqldb.Server server = new org.hsqldb.Server();

                    try {
                        server.setProperties(props);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        return;
                    }

                    server.start();
}
}
```

I get the error: 
[Thread[HSQLDB Server @4db602,6,main]]: Shutting down because there are no open databases

Can anyone help point out where I am going wrong.

Thanks for helping
Bala

Comment: Figured it out. Works now. For those interested server.setTrace(true);  gives out the information needed to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you commented, server.setTrace(true) helps in troubleshooting. So does server.setSilent(false).

But you shouldn't create and start a Runnable to start the server. The Server class does all of that and starts the necessary threads.

Comment: Yes Fred. The Server does create and manage the threads if I call it through main. But my requirement was in addition to shutdown the server when all clients are disconnected. Hence I opted to start hsqldb server via a thread so that when the parent process is closed the hsqldb server will also be shutdown. Unfortunately starting the server with shutdown=true did not work. That wouldve served my purpose adequately.

Answer (score 5):

You can use separate class to manage your HSQLdb server instance:

```java
public class DBManager {

    final String dbLocation = "c:\\temp\\"; // change it to your db location
    org.hsqldb.server.Server sonicServer;
    Connection dbConn = null;

    public void startDBServer() {
        HsqlProperties props = new HsqlProperties();
        props.setProperty("server.database.0", "file:" + dbLocation + "mydb;");
        props.setProperty("server.dbname.0", "xdb");
        sonicServer = new org.hsqldb.Server();
        try {
            sonicServer.setProperties(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return;
        }
        sonicServer.start();
    }

    public void stopDBServer() {
        sonicServer.shutdown();
    }

    public Connection getDBConn() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
            dbConn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb", "SA", "");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return dbConn;
    }
}
```

and use this class as that:

```java
public class WFProcess extends Thread {

    DBManager dbm = new DBManager();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new WFProcess()).start();
    }

    public void run() {
        dbm.startDBServer();

        // some usefull server work here
        Connection conn = dbm.getDBConn();
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS answers (num INT IDENTITY, answer VARCHAR(250))");
            stmt.executeQuery("INSERT INTO answers (answer) values ('this is a new answer')");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT num, answer FROM answers");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("Answer number: " + rs.getString("num")
                        + "; answer text: " + rs.getString("answer"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // end of usefull server work

        dbm.stopDBServer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For HSQL 2.3.x, refer below to run HSQL as a WebServer (HSQL server that uses port 80 for network.)

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37784679/15789