# How to start/stop hsqldb using maven?

Tags: java, maven, hsqldb

I'm trying to start and stop hsqldb using maven.
I want to start hsqldb server with a specific configuration (database) before the test phase and stop it afterwards and doo the same with an other configuration before and after application starts.

At the moment I start hsqldb with the maven exec plugin but the problem is that the server startup is blocking the complete maven build process (Hit **<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** to stop the server.)
Also there is no solution for stopping the server automatically.

Best regards

Hemeroc

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018066/starting-and-stopping-hsqldb-from-unit-tests

Comment: Sorry but this does not solve any questions. I'm not using hibernate, I dont want to start/stop hsqldb using source code, I want to start/stop it using Maven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check my hsqldb maven plugin :
https://github.com/avianey/hsqldb-maven-plugin

You can just start/stop it like jetty-maven-plugin or tomee-maven-plugin :

```
<plugin>

    <!-- current version -->
    <groupId>fr.avianey.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>hsqldb-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <!-- 
        default value for in memory jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/xdb
        override only values you want to change
    -->
    <configuration>
        <driver>org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</driver>
        <path>mem:test</path>
        <address>localhost</address>
        <name>xdb</name>
        <username>sa</username>
        <password></password>
        <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SYSTEM_USERS</validationQuery>
    </configuration>

    <!-- call start and stop -->
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>start-hsqldb</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>start</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>stop-hsqldb</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>stop</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>

</plugin>
```

Comment: It has **0 usages** in maven central, but integration tests is included in almost every java enterprise project in the world. So, this plugin definitely shouldn't be used ! (except a pet project) But, unfortunately, as we see no one want it even in pet projects.